# parsing urls from a text file to bash shell array

Tags: arrays, bash

i have a text file with many urls

```
www.example1.com
www.example2.com
www.example3.com
www.example4.com
```

How would i go about iterating through it, and parsing each url into an array instance..

i.e.

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
array[3]
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pure bash way:

```
array=($(<inFile))
```

then:

```
# list all the elements of array
echo "${array[@]}"

# echo num of elements in array
echo ${#array[@]}

## OR loop through the above array
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   echo $i # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

# 1st element of array
echo ${array[0]}

# 2nd element of array
echo ${array[2]}

# ...
```

Comment: thought it would work, but getting Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @user2466087, this requires bash or ksh or zsh: plain sh does not do arrays

Comment: @anubhava, you should get into the habit of quoting variables: `${array[@]}` and `"${array[@]}"` return different things.

Comment: @glennjackman so what should I do, Iam running a (.sh) script in which i have links inside a textfile.txt which need to be put in an array...?

Comment: test with `array=("a b" "c d")` to see the difference

Comment: @user2466087, if you use `#!/bin/sh` you cannot have arrays. Pick a different language: `#!/bin/bash` if it exists would be a good choice

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks for your comments and assistance you provided to OP. For me `echo "${array[@]}"` and `echo ${array[@]}` return same for  `array=("a b" "c d")`

Comment: yes, but try `for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done` versus `for i in ${array[@]}; do echo "$i"; done` -- *that* is where the quotes are important to keep the array elements intact.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks a lot for your response, yes I see your point and will make an edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

One concern with `( $(< file.txt) )` is if a line in the file can contain whitespace. Consider the array produced from

```
a b
c
d
```

The array would have 4 elements, not 3. URLs cannot contain whitespace, so it is not an issue here. For the general case, `bash` 4 provides a `mapfile` command which ensures that each line provides a single element for an array.

```
mapfile array < file.txt
```

is a one-step replacement for the following loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    array+=( "$line" )
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the array be in your script instead of reading a file you can use this approach.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(
"www.example1.com"
"www.example2.com"
"www.example3.com"
"www.example4.com"
)

for URL in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$URL"
done
```